# What CloudKit do and don't regarding multi user App

Tags: database-replication, cloudkit

First I am new in Xcode but start using Swift

I am so confused with the purpose of CloudKit (Document) if I want to develop multiuse app. Which normally I would use Web Services or Web base Application. It would be nice to use App in mobile and store all data in Cloud.

I have two questions:

1. Regardless of speed to deal with the iCloud, Can I make app with most or all data in iCloud and go to Appstore. Mean App only run when network available. (The reason I asked because some developers complained of Apple rejected with the reason "Specifically, your application requires iCloud support for the users to access this application, which can create poor user experience. ")
2. In case the app should maintain the syn of all data. I couldn't imagine how complicate to handle all in/out of the data. So the question: Is there any way to replicate iCloud data. just like some databases: MySql, Sql without much of the programming. Then I just focus on CoreData with replication features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning availability CloudKit is not very different from using web services. If there is no internet connection, then you will not be able to fetch data. How would you handle that if you were using web services? You should handle it the same way when using CloudKit. Just make sure that at least there is some functionality when the data is not available.

Your 2nd question is a bit broad. Yes, you could use CoreData syncing to iCloud. You could also just catch the fetched data using one of the many caching libraries that car available ([search CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/?q=cach))

Comment: I added support for local caching to https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao When using that, there is no need to consider connectivity. If you do not have internet access, then the last available data will be used.